# need to concatenate content place holder id with div id for javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to implement show/hide div when certain value is selected from drop down list. But I have to concatenate the content place holder id with the div name. If I do not do so, the code block is not working.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHideDiv() {

        var ddlPassport = document.getElementById('<%= ddlAnnualTax.ClientID %>').value;
        var dvPassport = document.getElementById('<%= dvPassport.ClientID %>').value;

        ContentPlaceHolder1_dvPassport.style.display = ddlPassport == "2" ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>


<div class="div_labels">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnnualTax" runat="server" Height="35px" Font-Size="Medium" Width="15%" Enabled="true" onchange="ShowHideDiv()">
            <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="select..." Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">first year</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">second year</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>   
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="div_labels"><div id="dvPassport" style="display: none" runat="server"> <input type="text" id="txtPassport" /></div></div>
</asp:Content>
```

In the code `ContentPlaceHolder1` is content place holder id and the div I need to show/hide is `dvPassport`. So I have to make `ContentPlaceHolder1_dvPassport` for the code to work. Why is it so ?

Comment: @mplungjan please try to read the problem before marking it as duplicate. `div` can not be set as `ClientIDMode="Static"` and the other solution provided in your link, I have already implemented. Please go through the code block provided in my post. Seems you have not enough knowledge of `ASP.NET`.  Please remove the duplicate label so that other can contribute. Thank You!

Comment: @mplungjan rather can google link, if you have any suggestions or answers regarding the problem, that will be of great help. Thank You!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828719/asp-net-4-0-webforms-how-to-keep-contentplaceholder1-out-of-client-ids-in-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHideDiv() {

        var ddlPassport = document.getElementById('<%= ddlAnnualTax.ClientID %>').value;
        document.getElementById('<%= dvPassport.ClientID %>').style.display = ddlPassport == "2" ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>
```

replace `ContentPlaceHolder1_dvPassport` with `document.getElementById('<%= dvPassport.ClientID %>')`. Hope it will work. But I can not say, what is the reason of adding content place holder id with div tag.

Comment: it worked.... but why in my code I have to add content place holder id, I have assigned the value of var, only that is the difference.